# base is not a constructor?

Tags: magento2

```
basePrototype = new base();
// we need to make the options hash a property directly on the new instance
// otherwise we'll modify the options hash on the prototype that we're
// inheriting from
basePrototype.options = $.widget.extend( {}, basePrototype.options );
$.each( prototype, function( prop, value ) {
    if ( !$.isFunction( value ) ) {
        proxiedPrototype[ prop ] = value;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: it showing error in jquery-ui base is not a constructor

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extend a jquery widget, you have to do:

```
$.widget('namespace.widgetname', base, {
    _init: function () {
        this._super();
    }
}
```

base should be the jquery-ui widget you want to extend from.

Id don't think that this syntax is correct :

```
$.widget.extend( {}, basePrototype.options );
```